# Receive boolean from contract to contract transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions

Is there a way to receive a boolean response when sending Ether from one contract to another contract function? 
I understand that transactions return transaction hashes, but is there a safe way to call the other contract function to receive a boolean, even if that other contract is a payable function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For transactions, there is no way to get return values immediately as transaction confirmation happens eventually. Transaction hash confirms the your transaction has been accepted by a node, but how successful the transaction (txns fail due to many reasons and most common to expect is out of gas), could be known only through the receipt.